# Link's Awakening "Thief"

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I needed some expensive items in the game and forgot it changes your name. I need to know if , in the 3ds download version, I can get rid of the title "Thief"?

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as the original, you won't be able to change your name. Once you steal from the shop, you are a Thief for life. (or until you erase that save.)